# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long when converting to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm reading an excel file with Pandas. One column has dates like this: `20160210`

I want to convert to datetime objects, so:

```
t = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

The following error arises:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Off-hand, I'd suspect some code that mistakenly assumes that `long` will be 64 bits everywhere, when on Windows compilers, it's 32 bits, even when targeting x86-64 CPUs.

You wouldn't be doing this on Windows by any chance, possibly with Python 3.5.0? [There was a recurrence of the Y2K38 bug for Windows builds when they were adding support for nanosecond timestamp precision](https://bugs.python.org/issue25155). If that's not the case, I would suspect something wrong on Pandas' side, in the same manner.

Comment: It certainly might be related to that, since it prints as '20160209L', and I was executing on windows (but with Anaconda Python 2.7.x). I'm testing on mac now and the error is different: 'signed integer is greater than maximum'